# Paging list of entities with restrcited access

Tags: security, design-patterns, pagination, enterprise

We have client-server application. To reduce response time we want to add paging of request. But there is one pitfal - security policy. The visibility of the object and the list of allowed actions are determined by the user's rights, roles, and its belonging to a particular department in the company hierarchy. Of course, this all changes dynamically.

**Example.** 
We have 1000 of entities. We made a page request from 100 entities. None of them are available to us due to business rules limitations. But next page probably will contain desired entities. Should we return an empty list? Or should we try to request next page automaticaly? What is the best practice for such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Paging should only show you the same resultset but one subset a time, without loading everything. Just take only the right data. If you now have unwanted results, maybe you introduce a bug while changing something else (let it be a sql query) than offset and limit.

Comment: Yes, I understand pagination principles. I've add example to my quetsion. Hope it will explain my problem more clearly.

Comment: Read only the right data. If you have to show only 200 of 1000 entities, then load only 200 and show them just in two pages.

Comment: I dont know which data is right. Yes, I read 200 entities. Than I need to analyze it to determine can user see this entity or not. There is cases when user cannot see no one entity from page. But it does not mead than rest of entities are invisible for him.